# How to get only values with not duplicated from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

Here is an array : `[2,2,3,3,5,7,9,9]`

from this array, i needs the values not it doesn't have an duplicate. how to get it?

`const onlyUniqueWithoutDup = array.filter((item) => !item.indexOf(array))`

looking the result as : `[5,7]`;

any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```js
const array = [2,2,3,3,5,7,9,9];

const result = array.filter((item, index, arr) => (arr.lastIndexOf(item) == arr.indexOf(item)));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Create an object where the keys will be the element from this array and then the value will the number of repetition. Then iterate this object and get the keys where value is only 1

```js
let data = [2, 2, 3, 3, 5, 7, 9, 9];


let newData = data.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  if (acc[curr]) {
    acc[curr] += 1;
  } else {
    acc[curr] = 1

  }

  return acc;
}, {});
let nonDup = [];

for (let keys in newData) {
  if (newData[keys] === 1) {
    nonDup.push(keys)
  }

}

console.log(nonDup)
```